# Filtering Eloquent collection data with $collection->filter()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to filter the following collection using the collection filter() method:

```
$collection = Word::all();
```

where the JSON output looks like this:

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"word": "dog",
"phonetic": "dog",
"mean": "pies",
"assoc": "some example text",
"author_id": "3",
"user_id": "3"
},
{
"id": "2",
"word": "sun",
"phonetic": "sun",
"mean": "słońce",
"assoc": "lorem ipsun dolor sit amet",
"author_id": "3",
"user_id": "2"
}, ...
]
```

However, when filtering the collection:

```
$filtered_collection = $collection->filter(function($item)
    {
        if($item->isDog())
        {
            return $item;
        }
 });
```

The filtered collection JSON output will look like this:

```
 {"1":
 {
 "id": "1",
 "word": "dog",
 "phonetic": "dog",
 "mean": "pies",
 "assoc": "some example text",
 "author_id": "3",
 "user_id": "3"
 },
 "2":
 {
 "id": "2",
 "word": "sun",
 "phonetic": "sun",
 "mean": "słońce",
 "assoc": "lorem ipsun dolor sit amet",
 "author_id": "3",
 "user_id": "2"
 }}
```

How can I keep the original JSON output when filtering a collection?
I'd like to have an array of my Eloquent model instances when filtering the original collection.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The collection's `filter` method calls `array_filter` on the underlying array, which, [according to the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/array_filter), preserves the array keys. This then results in your array being converted to a JavaScript object instead of an array.

Call `values()` on your collection to reset the keys on the underlying array:

```php
$filtered_collection = $collection->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->isDog();
})->values();
```

---

**Side note**: in newer versions of Laravel, you can use a [higher order message](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#higher-order-messages) to shorten the above into this:

```php
$filtered_collection = $collection->filter->isDog()->values();
```

Answer (score 12):

Just convert it to JSON with keeping in mind what the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections) states:

> **Note:** When filtering a collection and converting it to JSON, try calling the values function first to reset the array's keys.

So the final code would be:

```
$filtered_collection->values()->toJson();
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to give an explanation? This is the correct answer which is totally the same than the accepted/upvoted other one which only was better worded.

Comment: Downvoters are quick enough to downvote but never want to provide a reason

Answer (score 0):

Filtering from database could be done in this method also.

```
 //request the form value 
  $name=$request->name;
  $age=$request->age;
  $number=$request->phone;

 //write a query to filter
 $filter_result = DB::table('table_name')

 ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
 ->orWhere('age', 'like', '%'.$age.'%')
 ->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%'.$number.'%')

 ->get();

 if(is_null($filter_result)){
 return redirect()->back()->with('message',"No Data Found");

}else{
      return view('resultpage',compact('filter_result'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have eloquent collection array and you want to filter it from some attribute, you can try following filter to achieve this.

In my case, **$reports** is variable contain eloquent collection object.
and i want to filter from this collection with id attribute.

```
$filter_id = $reports->filter(function ($item) {
   return $item->id==5;
})->first();
```

now you have **$filter_id** variable that contains object with id=5.

you can access all attribute of id=5, like $filter_id->attribute_name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Laravel Collection Filter** and for matching text we can use PHP function

> **stripos()**

```
 $collection = collect($data)->filter(function ($item) use ($searchText) {
      return false !== stripos($item->key, $searchText);
 });
```